# Unable to Post a message to the WCF service from a Console application

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have WCF Service which has the below post method

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Job")]
bool PostJob(string inJob);
```

I'm calling the above function from a console application, below is the code

```
var uri = new Uri(_serviceurl);
var httpClient = CreateHttpRequest("POST", uri, _consumerKey, _consumerSecret, _apiToken, _apiTokenSecret, _serviceurl, _jobPollingPath);
var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(inJob);
httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uri.AbsoluteUri,new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xDoc)));
var msg = httpClient.GetAsync(uri).Result;
```

Now the problem is the call reaches the server and post method, but i have not received any value in the inJob Attribute. Can anyone let me know where i'm doing the mistake?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: where is json object passed?

Comment: it is passed to inJob Attribute of PostJob method i Suppose.
the _serviceurl parameter holds the value api+"/Job"